# How to separate values on a SQL union through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I'm using `mysql_fetch_array()` to do this, and testing my queries through phpMyAdmin.  And, as I thought they are both on the same row, is it possible to do this using `mysql fetch array()`?

Here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT xml FROM g2s_api_logs WHERE functioncode='MQX' AND cardnumber= '$cardnumber' AND        
            direction='out' AND date(datetime)='$date' AND time(datetime)='$time' UNION SELECT xml FROM 
            g2s_api_logs WHERE functioncode='MQX' AND cardnumber= '$cardnumber' AND direction='in' AND 
            date(datetime)='$date' AND time(datetime)='$time' ";
            $query= mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error().$sql);
            $array=mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $result= htmlspecialchars($array['?']);
            $response=htmlspecialchars($array['?']);
            mysql_close();
```

Please ignore the question mark; I dunno what to put into it yet. I run this one using phpMyAdmin and it worked. However I would like to separate their results in my display. Can I do that even if they are in the same row? Is there such a thing as fetch column?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a query like this:

```
select * from X where ...
union
select * from Y where ...
```

and you want to know if a particular row came from X or Y, then you can add a literal value to the SELECT clause to differentiate them:

```
select 'X' as came_from, * from X where ...
union all
select 'Y' as came_from, * from Y where ...
```

as long as the column names/aliases and types match the UNION will be happy with this sort of thing.